# Degrading vb.net win application performance

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, devexpress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Memory leak in .net application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822093/memory-leak-in-net-application)

I am working on a desktop application in VB.net 2005. The application contains a timer with an interval of 1 min. Each time the timer ticks, a set of functions gets executed, mostly database related. Initially the application runs fine. In processes(Task manager) the cpu usage goes to 100% every time the timer is invoked. But the timespan is around 1 sec(negligible). However as the time passes and after around 20 hours the time span of timer_tick increases to something like 20-30 secs. In this period cpu usage is 100% and the application does not responds. Gradually the time span of timer_tick increases to 1 min and the cpu uses gets stuck to 100% and the application does not responds. All objects are properly disposed. Moreover, this issue is with pentium 4 processors. The application runs fine on core 2 duo. 
I am using DevEx controls in my application.
The program runs fine with less records in database.
I have run the CLR Profiler. The code seems to be fine. 
Can you please help me in finding the real cause of the degrading performance.

Comment: -1 for asking the same question (word-by-word) twice.

Comment: @Heinzi I appreciate you looked at the question. But please read it fully. It contains some added details. However what i want to say is i had to modify my previous question and ask it again coz i m really not gettin the help. Neways thanks for ur vote.

Comment: @GeekOnDemand: You can always *modify* your old question, which will also cause it to bump up again on the front page. This is, in fact, the correct thing to do if you do not get a good answer (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/138661 for details). Just asking the question (albeit slightly modified) again -- to make matters worse, without linking to your old question -- is not appropriate on StackOverflow. Please do not take the downvote personally, it's just an indicator that it wasn't done "the right way".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could execute your code in background :

```
   Private WithEvents _bg As System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
    Public Sub executeYourCode()
        If _bg Is Nothing Then
            _bg = New System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
            AddHandler _bg.DoWork, AddressOf startExecute
            AddHandler _bg.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf endExecute
        End If
        If Not _bg.IsBusy Then  _bg.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub
```

Comment: then create a sub startExecute and paste your code

Comment: How does that help with the degrading performance issue? Won't the performance just degrade in the background thread? Yes, that would keep the application responsive, but it would not solve "the real cause of the degrading performance".

Comment: I totally agree with Heinzi. The same is happening. The CPU usage again increases to 100% but the only difference is this time its in background. :(